# Codeception pressKey ENTER does not work

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, enter, codeception

I am not familiar with codeception. I am trying to insert a text in an input field and press the ENTER button.

```
$I->fillField('#token-input-yw1', 'Some string');
$I->pressKey('#token-input-yw1', 13);
```

The text is entered but the enter key is not pressed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If anyone still have problem with pressing Enter key, here is a solution: (if you are using Webdriver with Selenium)

```
$I->pressKey('#input',WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone will find this useful.

See **http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#pressKey**

pressKey

Presses the given key on the given element. To specify a character and modifier (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>meta</kbd>), pass an array for `$char` with the modifier as the first element and the character as the second. For special keys use key constants from `WebDriverKeys` class.

> ```
> <?php
> // <input id="page" value="old" />
> $I->pressKey('#page','a'); // => olda
> $I->pressKey('#page',array('ctrl','a'),'new'); //=> new
> $I->pressKey('#page',array('shift','111'),'1','x'); //=> old!!!1x
> $I->pressKey('descendant-or-self::*[ * `id='page']','u');`  //=> oldu
> $I->pressKey('#name', array('ctrl', 'a'), \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::DELETE); //=>''
> ?>
> ```
>
> param `$element`
>
> param `$char` Can be char or array with modifier. You can provide
>   several chars.
>
> throws `\Codeception\Exception\ElementNotFound`

Please note, that you may need to add `\` or `\Facebook\WebDriver\` before `WebDriverKeys`:

`\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER`

Comment: Using it in helper, I need to add `\ ` as for `\WebDriverKeys::ENTER`. Else it will throw an error `Fatal error: Class 'Codeception\Module\WebDriverKeys' not found`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I pressed enter this way:

```
$I->executeJS('event.keyCode=13');
$I->fillField('input onkeypress=','13');
$I->pressKey('photo_link', '13');
```

But it didn't work.

I fixed it with the next code:

```
$I->executeJS("$('input#photo_link').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 13}));");
```

It equals enter key, try it.